# OneClick application deployment issue

Tags: wpf, oneclick

We have a WPF oneclick application where we have content that is updated from the web server and the files are copied into the application content directories.

It seems that there is a directory that is where content is read from but I can't find it. There seems to be 2 directories that I can find through application variables:
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory

The first one gives this directory:
%USER_DIR%\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\Z7CC6XEX.WZ6\AMHN5JKE.24H\gear..tion_58b3e06760c5809e_0001.0000_8bdd947f29008ffc

The second one gives this directory:
%USER_DIR%\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\Data\DCTM6YKT.LZQ\EOCXOVVB.VJC\gear..tion_58b3e06760c5809e_0001.0000_8bdd947f29008ffc\Data

The directory I am interested in is this:
%USER_DIR%\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\Z7CC6XEX.WZ6\AMHN5JKE.24H\gear...exe_58b3e06760c5809e_0001.0000_none_ee6c716212f37acf

I've looked through all the application variables, and can't find a way to get this directory.

Does anyone know how I can get this directory and why it is different?

Comment: I've never heard of that one. Maybe it's from an old install. Why do you want it?

Comment: To be clear: when you say "where we have content that is updated from the web server", you mean your application downloads data and saves it locally?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "get this directory" but on Win 7 this dir is located at `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\Data`

Howerver, your best option, IMO, is to just create a dir for your app in %APPDATA% folder and store your content there...

Comment: The problem is that in the xaml content, the image source is as follows:
<Image Source="images/gearup_header_se.jpg" />. this location resolves to the location I specified above (which I can't find as an application variable). This is the problem that I am looking to solve.

Comment: @user1146148 This isn't an answer to the question you posted, so I can't post it as an answer, but it may be a solution to your problem.  Include the image in your project, and use the 'Resource' Build Action.  No need to copy to output.  Then reference it with a pack URI like so: `<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/images/gearup_header_se.jpg" />`